# How to add correctly numbered footnotes in RevTex4-1

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, footnotes

So, I'm using [RevTex4-1](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) and at some point I need to add a footnote, which in Revtex goes to the bibliography. However, the footnote is not being numbered according to the natural numeration of the bibliography: all footnotes are appearing in the last numbers. For instance, in this example:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,showpacs,superscriptaddress,groupedaddress]{revtex4}

\begin{document}

This is a test~\cite{a} where I want correct footnotes~\footnote{footnote 1}, 
i.e. footnotes that are correctly numbered in the bibliography~\cite{b}.

\bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

(where references is just a simple bib file with two entries, a and b), the produced document appears as

> This is a test [1] where I want correct footnotes [3], i.e. footnotes
>   that are correctly numbered in the bibliography [2].

which is clearly not the desired behavior of numbered bibliography.

Any solutions?

**Edited:**
with "Any solutions?" I meant: How can I make the footnotes to have the bibliographic numbering according to their first appearance in the text? In the example above, this should be

> This is a test [1] where I want correct footnotes [2], i.e. footnotes
>   that are correctly numbered in the bibliography [3].

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be normal. Remember that your paper will be processed again before publication. Here's subsection V.A of the documentation:

> If you are using numbered citations (numerical or num- bered author-year), footnotes are by default incorporated into the reference section along with your bibliographic entries. This automated feature is only effective if you use BibTeX to prepare your bibliography.
>
> Author-year style bibliography does not lend itself to such a treatment, so by default footnotes appear in text as is usual. However, be advised that, if your article is accepted for publication, footnotes may be incorporated into text during the production process.

So, don't worry: the class does this on purpose.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
  title = {Quantum cryptography using any two nonorthogonal states},
  author = {Bennett, Charles H.},
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
  volume = {68},
  number = {21},
  pages = {3121--3124},
  numpages = {3},
  year = {1992},
  month = {May},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.68.3121},
  publisher = {American Physical Society}
}

@article{b,
 author={Bonfrate, G. and Harlow, M. and Ford, C. and Maxwell, G. and Townsend, P.D.},
 journal={Electronics Letters},
 title={Asymmetric Mach-Zehnder germano-silicate channel waveguide interferometers for quantum cryptography systems},
 year={2001},
 month={jun},
 volume={37},
 number={13},
 pages={846--847},
 doi={10.1049/el:20010508}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,showpacs,superscriptaddress,groupedaddress]{revtex4}

\begin{document}

This is a test~\cite{a} where I want correct footnotes~\footnote{footnote 1}, 
i.e. footnotes that are correctly numbered in the bibliography~\cite{b}.

Another footnote~\footnote{footnote 2}.

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your answer, or you my question. My issue is not that footnotes are going to the bibliography. My issue is that they are numbered *in the end* of it. As far as I know, the bibliographic numbering should be according to the first appearing of the entry in the text.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Nothing in the documentation suggests that. This would mix footnotes with citations and I don't think this is what RevTeX wants. Actually footnotes are implemented as endnotes, so it's normal that they appear at the end of the bibliography.

Comment: Ok. but both Physical Review Letters and Physical Review E uses what I'm asking for (e.g. http://prl.aps.org/pdf/PRL/v110/i18/e182301 Ref. [32], http://pre.aps.org/pdf/PRE/v87/i4/e042136 Ref. [23] are both "footnotes").

Comment: @J.C.Leitão I can't access those links.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot provide you the papers. Basically are two examples where the footnotes (not citations, but actual comments from the authors) are numbered according to their first appearance in the text. Nevertheless, I edited the question in order to clarify what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Just use ReVTeX 4.1.  Although the question says you are using ReVTeX 4.1, the example file's documentclass line has revtex4.  Replace that by revtex4-1:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,showpacs,superscriptaddress,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

This is a test~\cite{a} where I want correct footnotes~\footnote{footnote 1}, 
i.e. footnotes that are correctly numbered in the bibliography~\cite{b}.

\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

and the footnotes will be mixed in with the references, as you wanted.